# Why are my divs all displaying in the same location on hover?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to create a top menu. I have created this which gets the components to become visible when they have to, but my problem is that I don't know how to get each `menu-sub-item` to display **under** the hovered button.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.menu {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.menu-main-item:hover+.menu-sub-item {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}

.menu-sub-item {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-sub-item:hover {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <button class="menu-main-item">This is 1</button>
  <div class="menu-sub-item">
    <button>Sub 1.1</button>
    <button>Sub 1.2</button>
    <button>Sub 1.3</button>
  </div>
  <button class="menu-main-item">Ok 2</button>
  <div class="menu-sub-item">
    <button>Sub 2.1</button>
    <button>Sub 2.2</button>
    <button>Sub 2.3</button>
  </div>
  <button class="menu-main-item">Another 3</button>
  <div class="menu-sub-item">
    <button>Sub 3.1</button>
    <button>Sub 3.2</button>
    <button>Sub 3.3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd need to wrap each button & sub-menu in a separate div and apply `position:relative` to that.

Comment: @Paulie_D that I have done below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your menu item in div and then float it to left, **Done the Work**

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.menu {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100vw;
}
.menu .menuitem{
  float:left;
  margin-left:20px;

}
.menu-main-item:hover+.menu-sub-item {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}

.menu-sub-item {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

.menu-sub-item:hover {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menuitem">
    <button class="menu-main-item">This is 1</button>
    <div class="menu-sub-item">
      <button>Sub 1.1</button>
      <button>Sub 1.2</button>
      <button>Sub 1.3</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="menuitem">
    <button class="menu-main-item">Ok 2</button>
    <div class="menu-sub-item">
      <button>Sub 2.1</button>
      <button>Sub 2.2</button>
      <button>Sub 2.3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menuitem">
    <button class="menu-main-item">Another</button>
    <div class="menu-sub-item">
      <button>Sub 3.1</button>
      <button>Sub 3.2</button>
      <button>Sub 3.3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I would use an unordered list (turning your `.menu` element into a `ul`) so you can position the `.menu-sub-item` element relatively to its list-item.

you need to set `position: relative` to the `li` element, and `white-space: nowrap` to the buttons, so the caption will overflow their container.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.menu {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li { position: relative; }

.menu button { 
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap; }


.menu-main-item:hover+.menu-sub-item {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}

.menu-sub-item {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-sub-item:hover {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <button class="menu-main-item">This is 1</button>
    <div class="menu-sub-item">
      <button>Sub 1.1</button>
      <button>Sub 1.2</button>
      <button>Sub 1.3</button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="menu-main-item">Ok 2</button>
    <div class="menu-sub-item">
      <button>Sub 2.1 and some other text</button>
      <button>Sub 2.2</button>
      <button>Sub 2.3</button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="menu-main-item">Another 3</button>
    <div class="menu-sub-item">
      <button>Sub 3.1</button>
      <button>Sub 3.2</button>
      <button>Sub 3.3</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Any reason I should pick your answer? I feel like @Ahmed says Reinstate Monica's answer is much easier and works just fine

Comment: It's up to you. Anyway the answers are different. If you choose the float approach just remember to clear the float.

Comment: I upvoted both your answers :) Thank you! I just feel like his answer is easier. Easy is always good :)